# CatkinMake Error in DS325 "depth camera"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,
I try to use DS325 depth camera.
To get the following URL' s node, I executed the command "git clone [https://github.com/Myzhar/ros_depthsense_camera.git"](https://github.com/Myzhar/ros_depthsense_camera.git%22).

https://github.com/Myzhar/ros_depthsense_camera

Finally , I executed "CatkinMake",but I encountered the following error.

Error message :

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
DEPTHSENSE_LIBRARY
    linked by target "depthsense_camera_node" in directory /home/username/catkin_ws/src/ros_depthsense_camera

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/username/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/username/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

My development environment is Ubuntu14.04 and Indigo.

How should I resolve the error? Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268619/catkinmake-error--in-ds325-%22depth-camera%22/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2017-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your reply.

I resolve the problem by executing the following command.

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
wget http://files.djduff.net/Download/DepthSense/DepthSenseSDK-1.9.0-5-amd64-deb.run
chmod u+x DepthSenseSDK-1.9.0-5-amd64-deb.run
sudo ./DepthSenseSDK-1.9.0-5-amd64-deb.run # accept agreement
```

After that I can access the path `/opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK.`

---

Originally posted by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) with karma: 104 on 2017-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamienJadeDuff](https://answers.ros.org/users/2651/damienjadeduff/) on 2019-08-24**:
I deleted that file which I just put to share for a project - I don't think the creator would be happy with my hosting it. But there are versions of the SDK floating around online still.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would report this over at the issue tracker of that repository.

But in general: just cloning a repository *is not enough*. You'll have to make sure to have installed *all dependencies*. In the case of the SoftKinetic cameras, that means installing the DepthSense SDK.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-08-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1